# After building and publishing to IIS I always see production build when debug is used in publish commands

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, ng-build, dotnet-publish

I'm having a problem installing a dev version of my Angular/Dotnet app to IIS.
It seems like even when building the project as a dev/debug version and running it in IIS, the app informs me via a startup email I've created that it's **always** in production mode!

Steps to build and install in IIS:

1. > ng build --debug -> builds files to a "wwwroot" folder in my dot net API project
2. > dotnet publish --configuration Debug -> creates the publish folder with all files in bin folder
3. copy and paste 'publish' folder files to IIS folder
4. start the app in IIS manager -> see the site running in the browser

Now in my startup.cs file under the configure method, I have created this email code below to send me an email on startup. It's there to inform me if I'm in dev or prod mode. And it keeps saying production.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Host = email.host.com; 
            client.Port = 25; 
            client.EnableSsl = false;
            using (var emailMessage = new MailMessage())
            {
                emailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("myemailaddress@email.com"));
                emailMessage.From = new MailAddress("Startup@Somewhere.com");
                emailMessage.Subject = "Startup in: " + (env.IsDevelopment() ? "Development" : "Production");
                emailMessage.Body = "email body"; 
                client.Send(emailMessage);
            }
        }
     }
```

Am I building the projects incorrectly for dev?

Comment: Debug or release build has nothing to do with the environment, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: ok I think I see now. "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" controls the dev or prod env. But I want to know what controls the appsettings.json/appsettings.Development.json files and which one is used?

Comment: Again that's documented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1 and you can do simple experiments to dig further into it.